# como poner addEventListener para un array?

Tags: javascript, eventos

intento poner varios eventos para un mismo tipo de input, investigando me tope con que se puede hacer un array de todos los inputs llamados y con un for agregarlos, ejemplo:

```
let input_date = document.querySelectorAll('.input_fecha');

for (var i = 0; i < input_date.length; i++) {
    input_date[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log("mensaje");
    });
}
```

El inconveniente que le encuentro es que solo acepta funciones anónimas

Mi pregunta es hay algun otro metodo de llamar a todos los inputs y darles eventos sin hacer el for,asi como con Jquery que solo seria (intento no utilizar mucho Jquery)

```
$('input[type=date]').click(function(){
    console.log("mensaje");
});
```

si tengo que utilizar este metodo pero en diversos elementos, que tanto puede alentar el tiempo de carga?

Comment: Quizá ya te lo has planteado pero: Si la función anónima es el problema, lo que puedes hacer es llamar a tu función desde la anónima. `() => { miFuncion() }` No le veo gran inconveniente, en realidad no conozco qué tan ineficiente puede ser.
No veo otra forma de hacer lo que pides, sin jQuery, aunque yo usaría [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) en lugar del for normal.

Comment: Puedes hacer lo siguiente si no quieres pasar funciones anónimas. Puedes pasar la referencia de la función quieres que se ejecute. `function miFuncion(e) { console.log(e); } for(...) { input_date[i].addEventListener('click', miFuncion);}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos soluciones:

Por un lado, la función no tiene por qué ser anónima:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

//declaramos la función que se ejecutará cuando ocurre el evento
function selectedInput(event) {
  let input = this.target;
  console.log('Has introducido',event.data,'en el input',this.name);
}

//usamos el nombre de la función para asignarla a cada evento, reusándola
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('input', selectedInput));
```

```html
<input type="text" name="n1"/>
<input type="text" name="n2"/>
<input type="text" name="n3"/>
<input type="text" name="n4"/>
<input type="text" name="n5"/>
```

Y por otro lado, si quieres evitar muchos *event listeners*, puedes poner uno *general* en el padre de los elementos, que escuchará todos los eventos ocurridos dentro:

```js
const divWithInputs = document.querySelector('div');

//de nuevo, declaramos una función
function selectedInput(event) {
  console.log('evento capturado en', this);
  let input = event.target;
  console.log('Pero realmente ha sido lanzado desde',input);
  console.log('Has introducido',event.data,'en el input',input.name);
}

//escuchamos cualquier evento 'input' que ocurra en el elemento y en sus hijos
divWithInputs.addEventListener('input', selectedInput);
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="n1"/>
  <input type="text" name="n2"/>
  <input type="text" name="n3"/>
  <input type="text" name="n4"/>
  <input type="text" name="n5"/>
</div>
```

Comment: cual seria el evento input? creo es click... seria bueno tambien agregar una validacion `input.nodeName =="INPUT"` por si el padre contiene mas elementos que solo inputs.

Comment: El evento `input` se lanza cuando el valor de un input varía y el foco pasa a otro elemento